# Situation with my Entities model after publishing asp mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, publish

I have an asp mvc project that uses entity framework 5, it uses simplemembership authorization. The problem is that when InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute creates the tables in the production (it's a shared hosting environment) server, I noticed it prefixes my tables with a different schema. So I went and changed all the tables to that schema.

/************* UPDATE *********************/
The reason I changed the table schema was that the queries I ran against the tables created with a different schema didn't work, so I changed all of the tables and specified a different schema name in the properties of the model in VS, but it didn't work.

But now none of the queries I run in the code work, and the application can't find my tables. Creating and authorizing users works ok, because it uses WebSecurity methods, but my custom methods do not work.

Is there a way to do this, how can I publish an edmx file that is consistent with my database in production server?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my own solution although it was very simple indeed, but because I understand this is kind of an odd situation and usually there should be no need to update anything in the model of EF after development. However, as I mentioned, my shared server didn't allow the automatic creation of tables, (as they were created by the simplemembership component) so I had to do this:

Run the scripts on the server.

Then regenerate the entire model, but connecting to the production server for this purpose.